# Where the type mismatch error 13 comes from in this case?

Tags: vba, excel

One of my Excel worksheets contains many data and the cells are in number format. (for instance it is filled with numbers like 1,02458)

In another worksheet I am trying to do some calculus based on the first worksheet, and for this I am using VBA code:

```
Dim sum, price, strike As Double
sum= 0
strike = 0.02

For k = 1 To 5000

sum= sum+ Worksheets("Feuille1").Cells(k, 7).Value - strike


Next k
```

When I try to run this the line with the sum corresponds to the error 13 type mismatch.

I have tried things such as changing the cell format, and even using Variant instead of Double but it changed nothing. How to avoid the type mismatch ?

Comment: Try to compare `Var_Type` of `strike`, `Var_Type` of `.Cells(k, 7).Value` , and also `Var_Type` of `sum`.

Comment: Side note: You need to specify a type for **every** variable. In `Dim sum, price, strike As Double` only the last is `Double` the first two are `Variant`. Use `Dim sum As Double, price As Double, strike As Double` instead.

Comment: Thanks Peh I applied your advice. @Clement B, if I print the Var_Type of .Cells(k,7).Value it seems to be "Empty", I don't understand why.

Comment: Try using Sheets("Feuille1") instead of Worksheets. I don't know if it'll work. If not, show me the column 7 of your worksheet.

Comment: Is there a header in Sheet "Feuille1" range "G1"? In that case you're trying to add a string to the sum, which will lead to type mismatch.
If the digits start at row 2, then change to `For k = 2 to 5000`

Comment: It does seem like the problem comes from the k in Cells, since when I replace it with 3 for instance it works.

Comment: @ClementB Avoid using `Sheets()` unless you know why. The `worksheets` collection only contains worksheets but the `sheets` object also contains charts etc. So it doesn't make any sense to use `sheets` here!

Comment: Thanks to all of you, @Rik Sportel you were right, there was a header in G1. If you want to answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a header in Sheet "Feuille1" range "G1"? 
In that case you're trying to add a string to the sum, which will lead to type mismatch. If the digits start at row 2, then change your loop to

```
For k = 2 to 5000
```